# Installing Craft 3 without composer

Tags: craft3, install

So i copied the craft files onto my server. Web directory went into my public folder. I type in my address, I get the Craft service unavailable page, good so far. 
I cant get to the installer. http://HOSTNAME/index.php?p=admin takes me to url/admin not found on the server. 
What can I look for to see why Im not getting to the install directory.?

Thank you.

Comment: Did you put a .htaccess file? with mod_rewrite rules in it?

Comment: htaccess is now in, had one in but added an extra letter when saving it somehow........ now /admin loads, but getting another error. 
Internal Server error, Unsupported DB driver value

Comment: Did do the server check beforehand, gave me the green light..

Answer (score 1):

Had missed copying over a hidden .env file. Once I copied over to server, install completed. Thanks to all who commented..

Comment: Fidel, for my information, where did you place the craft directory and did you have to edit the index.php file, as to point it to that craft directory, or did you maintain the existing structure, placing the craft flies next to the public folder like the structure of the downloaded zip?

Comment: Craft contents into my root, web folder contents into my public folder. No editing of index file, just make sure you copy over all the hidden files in the crafts download, htaccess and env files.

Answer (score 0):

HOSTNAME should be substitued for your server hostname e.g.:
http://myproject.test/index.php?p=admin

Comment: Yes, I used my servers host name.
Thanks